# Delete parameter from json URL with swift3

Tags: swift, string

I have a URL that looks like `123456_https://example.com`.
I want to delete every thing before the `_https:` part. At the end, the URL should look like `https://example.com`.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: [Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info) are the way to go. Match sth. like `^.*?http` and then replace its occurrence with `""`. [RegexPal](https://www.regexpal.com) is great for testing.

Comment: sorry i cannot understand you.can u please give me proper explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If the prefix is always a couple of characters ending with a underscore you can use this regular expression

```
let url = "123456_https://example.com"
let trimmedURL = url.replacingOccurrences(of: "^\\w+_", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

Comment: sorry but your answer not correct i cannot find out my proper link after split_

Comment: `trimmedURL` contains `https://example.com` as requested in the question

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this if you do not know how to use Regular Expressions

```
      // url string
  var url = "123456_https://example.com"
// seperate url by "_" and provides 123456 and https://example.com in urlArray
  let urlArray = url.components(separatedBy: "_")
// now to be safe
    if(urlArray.count == 2){
        // here you get your desired string
        let myUrl = urlArray[1]

    }
```

Comment: Accepting the answer will be sufficient :)